# Can I determine for what reason Visual Studio decides to compile a project?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

It's driving me nuts.
I'm on a new project and every time I change the slightest thing, the entire solution (79 projects) is recompiled.

It's sooooo slow and when I edit 1 line of code in the (ASP.NET MVC) controller: bang, the entire solution is recompiled.

Is there a way to check why Visual Studio is deciding that?

It will probably be the way the solution is setup, but I can't figure it out.

These are my build settings:

[image]
I thought about checking 'only build startup projects and dependencies on run' but there are multiple websites in one solution so I want them also compiled (when changed)

Comment: The screenshot is not relevant to this problem.  Nevertheless, you'll have to change the build output verbosity to "Detailed" so see the exact reason why it decided to rebuild everything.

Comment: Does it have an indication or a prefix where it shows the reason? Because just going through the whole file....